# Laravel Eloquent Models __construct method to call relations

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I want to have my model automatically call its relations when instantiated. As of now my model looks like this:

```
class AdminLog extends Model{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'admin_id');
    }
}
```

but when i try to do `dd(AdminLog::get()->first());`, it doesnt show any relations.

Edit#1: tried adding `parent::__construct();` inside the model's `__construct` method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongsTo()` **defines** a relationship, it doesn't load it.

First you need to define the relationship, then you can load it at any point using the `load` method.

```php
class AdminLog extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'admin_id');
    }
}

$log = AdminLog::first();
$log->load('user');
```

It is possible to load inside the constructor, but I would highly recommend against that. If you have 20 `AdminLog` objects then it will query the database 20 times, once for each object. That's inefficient.

What you should do instead is use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). This will query the users table just **once** for all 20 admin logs. There are many ways to do this, here is an example:

```php
$logs = AdminLog::take(20)
    ->with('user')
    ->get();
dd($logs->toArray());
```